# how to change the height of two views (One view shrink and the other expand) using objective c?

Tags: objective-c, uiview, uiviewcontroller

i have two views(A&B) in the same view controller(popOver window) and want to toggle between them, view A is larger than view B, when the popOver window first loads i want view A only to appear and when i press certain button inside it , it should shrink down to let view B appear above it, i tried to set the height of view B to fit into the all window when the window first load(Inside viewDidLoad)then reduce it's height and increase the height of the other view when a button is clicked, i try that code but it didn't change the height of the view !!

```
-(void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
UIView *contactsView=[self.view viewWithTag:2];// is this a correct initialization of a  uiView from a view in a storyBoard ?
CGRect frame=contactsView.frame;
frame.size.height+=100;
contactsView.frame=frame;
}
```

any idea about that will be helpful,thanks.

Answer (score 0):

As a general answer (I don't have time for more detail), I would use 3 views overall:

1) The view owned by your View Controller.
2) View A
3) View B

View A and B can be created in viewDidLoad of your view controller. Then set the frame of each of these for the position and size. Add them both to the view:

// in your .h file create these variable:

```
UIView* m_vA;
UIView* m_vB;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    m_vA = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 50.0, 50.0)] autorelease];
    m_vB = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:<your rect for View B>] autorelease];

    // The views will automatically be retained. 
    [self.view addSubview:vA];
    [self.view addSubview:vB];

    m_vB.hidden = YES;
}

// In your button callback, toggle the visibility of views
- (IBAction)buttonPressed:(id)sender
{
    // Toggle the visibility of views
    m_vA.hidden = !m_vA.hidden;
    m_vB.hidden = !m_vB.hidden;
}
```

// Dont forget to clean up the memory of these views in dealloc and viewDidUnload.

Comment: what's initWithRect , i'm using iOS SDK 5.1 ?

Comment: iOS SDK 5.1 automatically handles memory, there are no longer use of autorelease

Comment: it's initWithFrame... told you i was in a hurry.

Comment: Yes, use ARC if you don't want to learn about memory management. imo it's lame.

Comment: initWithFrame:CGRect--> which CGRect it will take?

Comment: how to get the CGRect of the view in the storyboard?

Comment: @chostDevil The CGRect is up to you. You have 2 different views that you want to show. Using CGRectMake(..) you can create the origins and size of each view.